# Using chai-as-promised in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, promise, protractor, chai

Following [this example](http://litutech.blogspot.com/2014/02/an-example-of-use-of-protractor-with.html) I can get tests working with the expect syntax but not with the should syntax.

The following works:

```
var expect = chai.expect;
describe('expect syntax', function() {
    it('should work', function() {
        ...
        expect(promise).to.eventually.eql('something');
    });
});
```

But this does not:

```
chai.should();
describe('should syntax', function() {
    it('should work', function() {
        ...
        (true).should.be.true;
        promise.should.eventually.eql('something');
    });
});
```

Since I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventually' of undefined` I assume that *should* does its usual thing of extending the Object prototype but this somehow doesn't apply to the webdriver promise Object. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [my issue](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/issues/57) and this [other issue](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/issues/40) that I somehow missed, it would appear that the source of the problem is that webdriverjs promises are based on promise/A and promise/B while chai-as-expected is expecting promise/A+ types promises.

Wrapping the websriverjs promise in a Q promise solved the issue:

`Q(webdriverjspromise).should.eventually.eql('something')`

Comment: Thanks. i was breaking my head around this for hours!

Answer (score 0):

This works for us..

```
  var element = $('#mainDiv');      
  expect(element.isEnabled()).to.eventually.to.equal(true, "Expect Button to be enabled.");
```

I'd make sure that the "promise' is really a promise, and does eql work? I've always used equal.

On a side note we're using Cucumber with Chai & Chai-as-promised but it shouldn't matter with the promise.

Comment: As I mentioned the expect syntax works fine. The should syntax doesn't seem to work with the webdriver promises though.